# CIFAR-10 Keras image data augmentation effect for one image only

Tags: tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

I want to show the effect of different data augmentation (randomly scaling, rotating and translating) on just one image. I plot the first image from x_train, however the second plot does not appear to have any changes.

I guess I am using datagen.flow wrongly, please advise on it. Thanks.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.python.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
x1=x_train[0]
print(x1.shape)
plt.imshow(x1)
plt.show()

# set up image augmentation
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=180, # Randomly rotate by degrees
    width_shift_range=0.2,  # For translating image vertically
    height_shift_range=0.2, # For translating image horizontally
    horizontal_flip=True,
    rescale=None,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)
datagen.fit(x_train)


# see example augmentation images
x_batch = datagen.flow(x_train)
x2=x_batch[0]
print(x2.shape)
```

The output shape of x2 is (32, 32, 32, 3) which is why i'm unable to plot it. Why are the dimensions like that and what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datagen.flow()` actually **returns** the (augmented) batches from `x_train`, it doesn't affect `x_train` inplace. You need to do it like this:

```py
x_batch = datagen.flow(x_train)[0]
img = x_batch[0] / 255
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, however I get this error: 
  File "C:/PythonProjects/tf2.py", line 26, in <module>
    plt.imshow(x_batch[0])
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 638, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Are your images grayscale? It might be because it had a shape of `(height, width 1)` instead of `(height, width)`. I edited my answer, try it now.

Comment: No its RGB (32x32x3). I still get an error with your new code:    TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: I saw the shape now has an added dimension after datagen.flow. What should I do? 
(32, 32, 32, 3). I have edited my post

Comment: Oh, so this essentially represents 32 images that are `(32, 32, 3)` each. I edited my answer, it should work now.

Comment: It still doesn't work, the plot is empty now. I get this message: "Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)."

Comment: I changed it again, try it one last time like this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Djib2011 for the suggestions. I found out its because the function will shuffle the images by default, so we can set shuffle = false to preserve the index.

```
x_batch = datagen.flow(x_train,shuffle=False)[0]
print(x_batch.shape)
x2=x_batch[0]
plt.imshow((x2.astype(np.uint8)))
plt.show()
```